# Tensorflow 2x - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on a Tensorflow project that needs to be upgraded to use tensorflow==2.2.0, and can no longer work with Tensorflow 1.x, due to comparability with other packages.

However, after upgrading, I'm getting the below error:

```
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .variables import variable
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/variables.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

The only help I can find regarding this error is to downgrade.

What, if any, is the recommend approach to migrate up to Tensorflow 2.x when using `tflearn`?

Comment: you got any idea which class of  tf.contrib you are relaying on?

Comment: I think it is `tflearn`

Comment: Or `add_arg_scope`

Comment: After some resreach i think you cant migrate to tensorflow 2.0 using tflearn, the whole purpose of tflearn is high level api for tf 1, which why tf.keras is here in tf 2.0 so migrating a wrapper in most case is impossible.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly possible. You have to rebuild different routines and several functions need to be altered accordingly. There are not 100% differences between 1.X and 2.X version, but at-least some functions are new and some old options are deprecated. If you upgrade step by step, you can see there are deprecation warnings for next level upgradations.